# Program won't output what it's supposed to

Tags: ruby

I am following  tutorial and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. It's outputting everything up to if down
             puts "we are going down the cave" I can't get it to output the else statement or anything afterwards. I am just learning and the answer is probably really simple.

```
   puts("Would you like to go up or down?")

 user_input = gets()

 down = "cave"
 up = "mountain" 

 if down
puts "we are going down the cave"

else up
puts "we are going up the mountain"



  puts("Pick a number between 1 and 100")

LOCATION = "cave"
NUMBER = gets()

if NUMBER == 100
puts "You've achieved enlightment in the #{LOCATION}! Spread joy around         the world!"
elsif NUMBER >= 50 > 100
puts "There are #{NUMBER} goblins in the #{LOCATION}. WE MUST FIGHT!"
elsif NUMBER > 20 > 50
puts "There is still hope that we will make it to the #{LOCATION}.    before the #{NUMBER} Snufflebums get us!"
 else NUMBER <= 20
puts "We have conquered the Goon Squad of the #{LOCATION}.. It only took us #{NUMBER} years!!!"



 end

 end
```

Comment: hmmm I change all of that and it still doesn't output anything after the down statement.

Comment: Great title. Programs which won't output what they are supposed to, don't get me started.

Comment: People can be so rude! I wasn't sure how to word the question. Should people learning just not be able able to ask questions? Chill out. If the title isn't clear enough for you keep browsing! Prick!

Answer (score 0):

`down` is "cave" and is always 'truthy' so `if down` is always, always true. You want to be testing the user_input, not the variable `down`

What I think you want is...

```
user_input = gets.chomp 
# you need the chomp to remove the return character

down = "cave"
up = "mountain" 

if user_input == down
  puts "we are going down the cave"

elsif user_input == up
  puts "we are going up the mountain"
end
# you need the end statement, otherwise everything that follows is part of the "else"
```

And remove the last `end`